# D3.js - stacked bar chart

Tags: d3.js

This is a similar query like [d3.js - group 2 data values in a stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522825/d3-js-group-2-data-values-in-a-stacked-bar-chart).

I am trying to work on a prototype.

I have the following csv

```
date,pass,fail,compid
01/2014,1,2,001
01/2014,11,5,002
02/2014,7,3,001
02/2014,8,1,002
03/2014,2,3,001
03/2014,6,1,002
```

I would like to show the total pass and fail on a date(inclusive of both comp id). So for 01/2014, the total pass is 12 and fail is 7. So on x-axis for jan-2014 i need a stacked bar which shows pass as 12 and fail as 7.

My working code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Pass vs Fail</title>

    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>


    <style type="text/css">

svg {
  width: 980px;
  height: 500px;
  border: solid 1px #ccc;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

label {  
    display: inline-block;  
    cursor: pointer;  
    position: relative;
    padding-left:1px;  
    margin-right: 5px;  
    font-size: 13px;  
}  


g.axis path, g.axis line {fill:none; stroke:black; shape-rendering:crispEdges;}


    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

<div id="container">
<br>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">


var w = 960,
    h = 500,
    p = [20, 50, 30, 20],
    x = d3.time.scale().range([1, 80]);

    y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h - p[0] - p[2]]),
    z = d3.scale.ordinal().range(["#819FF7", "#CB491A"]),
    parse = d3.time.format("%m/%Y").parse,
    format = d3.time.format("%b-%y");

    var tempdata;

    var xAxis=d3.svg.axis()
          .scale(x)
          .orient("bottom")
          .ticks(d3.time.month, 1)
              //.ticks(12)



   xAxis.tickFormat(d3.time.format("%b-%y"));


    /*var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .ticks(12)
    .orient("left");*/

var svg = d3.select("#container").append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)
  .append("svg:g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + p[3] + "," + (h - p[2]) + ")");

d3.csv("scanpassfail.csv", function(scan) {

  // Transpose the data into layers by cause.
  var scantypes = d3.layout.stack()(["pass", "fail"].map(function(scans) {
    return scan.map(function(d) {
      return {x: parse(d.date), y: +d[scans],z:d.compid,typescan:scans};
    });
  }));


  scan.forEach(function(d,i) {
    var y0 = 0;
    tempdata=d;
    d.date = d.date;
    d.pass = +d.pass;
    d.fail =+d.fail;
  }); 



  // Compute the x-domain (by date) and y-domain (by top).
  x.domain(scantypes [0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(scantypes[scantypes .length - 1], function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);

  // Add a group for each scan.
  var cause = svg.selectAll("g.scan")
      .data(scantypes)
    .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "scan")
      .style("fill", function(d, i) { return z(i); })
      .style("stroke", function(d, i) { return d3.rgb(z(i)).darker(); });

  // Add a rect for each date.
  var rect = cause.selectAll("rect")
      .data(Object)
    .enter().append("svg:rect")
      .attr("id", function(d,i) { return i + " comp " + d.z;  })
      .attr("x", function(d,i) { 
                        if (i ==0) 
                        { 
                            return x(d.x) ;
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            return x(d.x);
                        }} )
      .attr("y", function(d) { return -y(d.y0) - y(d.y); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
      .attr("width", 30)
    .on("mouseover", function(d){

                   return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
                                   .text((d.y))//d.typescan + " -  " + 
                                   .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px") 
                                   .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 20) + "px");      ;})
      .on("mousemove", function(d){

                      return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
                                   .text((d.y)) //d.typescan + " -  " + 
                                   .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px") 
                                   .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 20) + "px");      ;})

      .on("mouseout", function(d){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");}) 
      .on("click", function(d){});



  var tooltip = d3.select("#container")
    .append("div")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "visible")
    .text("Scanned vs UnScanned")
    .style("font", "Arial")
      .style("color", "white")
    .style("font-size", "14px");

  //Add x-Axis
    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    //.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0,80)"; })
    .call(xAxis)




  // Add a label per date.
  var label = svg.selectAll("text")
      .data(x.domain())
    .enter().append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x); })//x.rangeBand() / 4
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .text(format);

  // Add y-axis rules.
  var rule = svg.selectAll("g.rule")
      .data(y.ticks(5))
    .enter().append("svg:g")
      .attr("class", "rule")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(0," + -y(d) + ")"; });

  rule.append("svg:line")
      .attr("x2", w - p[1] - p[3])
      .style("stroke", function(d) { return d ? "#fff" : "#000"; })
      .style("stroke-opacity", function(d) { return d ? .7 : null; });

  rule.append("svg:text")
      .attr("x", -15)
      .style("font-family","Arial 12px")
      .attr("dy", ".25em")
      .text(d3.format(",d"));


var Rectangles = [
   { "x_axis": 870, "y_axis": -400,"color" : "#819FF7"},
   { "x_axis": 870, "y_axis": -440,"color" : "#CB491A"}];


var rectangle= svg.selectAll("#container").data(Rectangles).enter().append("rect");

var RectangleAttrb = rectangle.attr("x", function (d) { return d.x_axis; })
                       .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y_axis; })
                       .attr("width",30 )
               .attr("height",20)
                       .style("fill", function(d) { return d.color; });


var text = svg.append('text').text('Pass')
           .attr('x', 904)
           .attr('y', -390)
       .attr("style", "font-size: 18; font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif")
           .attr('fill', 'black')

var text = svg.append('text').text('Fail')
              .attr('x',904)
              .attr('y', -430)
          .attr("style", "font-size: 18; font-family: Helvetica,sans-serif")
              .attr('fill', 'black')



});

    </script>
  </body>
</html>    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

though i have tried to group the values based on date, it didnot work out.

```
scan.forEach(function(d,i) {
        var y0 = 0;
        tempdata=d;
        d.date = d.date;
        d.pass = +d.pass;
        d.fail =+d.fail;
      });
```

I am stuck at the place where i can add the column values based on similarity of the column value.

Comment: Next time, instead of asking a new, near-identical question, edit your original question with more information.  Editing will bump it up the active questions list and show people you are still interested.  I'll answer there, and am marking this one to be closed as duplicate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [d3.js - group 2 data values in a stacked bar chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522825/d3-js-group-2-data-values-in-a-stacked-bar-chart)