# Loading external csv file in jsfiddle

Tags: d3.js, jsfiddle, dc.js

I am trying to create a jsfiddle for one of the dc.js examples. I am not able to load an external file using a URL and `d3.csv()`.

Can someone please suggest how to load a csv file using `d3.csv` in jsfiddle.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can, but there are alternative such as [Bl.ocks](http://bl.ocks.org/)

Comment: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/) is another good option.

Comment: @Andy897 : Try Plunker you might like. I have the same situation as you, and this is how it looks like in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/RYejCrn3N92bMDWr0NMY?p=preview)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The approach I usually use for CSV data in JSFiddle examples is

a. Put the data in a `<pre>` block at the end of the HTML mark-up, usually with the id "data".

b. Add `pre {display:none;}` to the CSS.

c. Replace the `d3.csv(filename, callback)` function call with a `d3.csv.parse(text)` call, using the text content of the `<pre>` block as the input to the parse function.

Because the parse function doesn't use a callback, it just returns the data array, you need to save that output in a variable of the same name as your callback data parameter.

In other words, if your example looks like

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {

   if(error){console.log("Could not read " + "data.csv");

   /* Do something with `data` here */

});
```

The JSFiddle-friendly version would look like:

```
//d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {

//   if(error){console.log("Could not read " + "data.csv");

var data = d3.csv.parse( d3.select("pre#data").text() );

   /* Do something with `data` here */

//});
```

If you would rather have a full working example that uses the file-reading methods as intended, there are other options as mentioned in the comments.  [Tributary](http://tributary.io/inlet/) also allows external data files I think.

Comment: P.S.  [Here's an example using the above technique](http://fiddle.jshell.net/NYpHG/2/); it's from [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21567970/3128209).  [Here's another example](http://jsfiddle.net/KjrGF/12/), which originally had four different data files -- all are plunked into the fiddle as separate `<pre>` blocks; you can also see the original file-reading calls commented out in the code. That example came from [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21923560/3128209).

Comment: Hi Amelia, Kudos to you for the great reply. Seems like you work actively with d3 and other child libraries like nvd3 and dc. Here is another doubt of mine, if you can please have a look when you get a chance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897142/grouping-charts-in-dc-js ... Thank You!

Comment: @AmeliaBR : I tried your solution, and I still stuck at something, I hope you don't take a look at my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bheng/b0z5hc71/1/) I have the same goal as the OP

Comment: A slight syntactical variant, I replaced:  d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

Comment: with: var data = d3.csv.parse( d3.select("pre#data").text() );
data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
    });

Comment: For version 4 of d3 use: `d3.csvParse(d3.select("pre#data").text());`