# why does one chart not filter another in dc.js?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I am not able to understand how dc groups chart. So that the change in one filter reflects in all others. 
I have a simple code with two series charts. When I draw brush on one, it does not filter the other. Not sure why ? Can someone please have a quick look at the small code and suggest.

```
d3.csv("data/compareData.txt", function(data) {

  ndx = crossfilter(data);
  runDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return [+d3.time.format.iso.parse(d.timestamp), +d.meterid]; });
  frequencyGroup = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d.frequency; });
  magnitudeGroup = runDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d.magnitude; });


 frequencyChart
    .width(768)
    .height(480)
    .chart(function(c) { return dc.lineChart(c).interpolate('basis'); })
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([1366621166000, 1366621179983]))
    .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([90, 100]))
    .brushOn(true)
    .yAxisLabel("Measured Speed km/s")
    .xAxisLabel("Run")
    .elasticY(true)
    .dimension(runDimension)
    .group(frequencyGroup)
    .mouseZoomable(false)
    .seriesAccessor(function(d) {return +d.key[1];})
    .keyAccessor(function(d) {return +d.key[0];})
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {return +d.value;})
    .legend(dc.legend().x(350).y(350).itemHeight(13).gap(5).horizontal(1).legendWidth(140).itemWidth(70));
  frequencyChart.yAxis().tickFormat(function(d) {return d3.format(',d')(d);});
  frequencyChart.margins().left += 40;

 magnitudeChart
    .width(768)
    .height(480)
    .chart(function(c) { return dc.lineChart(c).interpolate('basis'); })
    .x(d3.time.scale().domain([1366621166000, 1366621179983]))
    .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([90, 100]))
    .brushOn(true)
    .yAxisLabel("Measured Speed km/s")
    .xAxisLabel("Run")
    .elasticY(true)
    .dimension(runDimension)
    .group(magnitudeGroup)
    .mouseZoomable(false)
    .seriesAccessor(function(d) {return  +d.key[1];})
    .keyAccessor(function(d) {return +d.key[0];})
    .valueAccessor(function(d) {return +d.value;})
    .legend(dc.legend().x(350).y(350).itemHeight(13).gap(5).horizontal(1).legendWidth(140).itemWidth(70));
  magnitudeChart.yAxis().tickFormat(function(d) {return d3.format(',d')(d);});
  magnitudeChart.margins().left += 40;

      dc.renderAll();

});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the same dimension to group on both charts.

> a grouping intersects the crossfilter's current filters, except for
>   the associated dimension's filter. Thus, group methods consider only
>   records that satisfy every filter except this dimension's filter. So,
>   if the crossfilter of payments is filtered by type and total, then
>   group by total only observes the filter by type.

from the [crossfilter API doc](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference)

One solution is to create a `runDimension2` similar to `runDimension` and do your second chart using this dimension instead.