# changing from html to jsp : referenceerror d3 is not defined

Tags: html, jsp, d3.js, dc.js

I have a html file in which I draw some svgs using dc.js and d3.js .. The moment I change the extension to jsp. It starts throwing :

Uncaught ReferenceError: d3 is not defined  in dc.js

No clues why :( .. Any suggestions ?

This is how I am inclusing js in html/jsp

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/d3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/crossfilter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../javascripts/dc.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your webserver is probably trying to interpret it as a JSP. Do you have any JSP code in there?

Comment: yes, I do have jsp code. And once I change the extension of .html to .jsp .. webserver should interpret it as JSP .. isn't it ?

Comment: Well yes (depending on your webserver configuration), but it may not interpret the HTML part in the same way.

Comment: I think I have not put the question right way. So here I try again. :) .. If I open index.html .. all is good.  If I rename it to index.jsp then only I get the reference error d3 is not defined.

Comment: Lars, looks like you are playing with d3.js and other related stuff extensively. :) .. If you can please have a look at this question as well .. when you get a chance.

Comment: Lars, looks like you are playing with d3.js and other related stuff extensively. :) .. If you can please have a look at this question as well .. when you get a chance. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22897142/grouping-charts-in-dc-js

Comment: Could you post the complete code please?

Comment: You can first confirm that the .js files are loading properly by viewing the source and clicking on script src links and make sure you are not getting 404 not found. Then you can remove d3 stuff and confirm that jquery is working. If both are working at least you know there is something wrong with d3 (which I doubt)

Comment: @Andy897 Have you been able to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

See the thing is when you use only html then, at that time, its just a html page directly accessing the recourse. In case of JSP, it's always MVC architecture  so JSP cannot directly access the recourse. You have to provide the path of the file using JSP tags. Following gives an example of how you can do it.
Suppose I created a file structure under myProject -> Webapp like this :
              res -> mytheme -> js -> filename.js
then do the following :

1) Include the following lines in servlet-config.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/res/**" location="/res/mytheme/" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

It tells the framework that whenever you encounter /res/ then replace it with res/mytheme/ & thats where the file is present.

2) In the JSP file, Use the following line:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/res/js/filename.js"/>"></script>
```

Hope this is helpful. **It worked for me.**