# How to read a csv file in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, jsfiddle, dc.js

I am trying to read an external csv in JSFiddle using d3.js

I have followed the instructions suggested [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890836/loading-external-csv-file-in-jsfiddle), but still no success.

[THIS is my JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cra8e6s8/12/)

```
   d3.csv.parse( d3.select("pre#ddata").text(), function (data) {...
```

Can someone please suggest what I a doing wrong here

Comment: Why do you think there is something wrong? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: You are not reading from an external .csv file in your fiddle. Can you get your visualization to show up with local data first?

Comment: In the console it says that data is not defined. and even if I try to alert data is says undefined. If pre#ddata was read properly, data would have been defined

Comment: @GVashist .. I am using local data only .. at least have a look at JSFiddle first

Comment: Yes. I can see that. Your question is directed towards _read an external csv_ which is why I asked if you managed to get it working with local data and are having issues using an actual external csv but after some of the other comments, its clear you have an issue making the local data work in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsFiddle is missing some closing curly brackets somewhere (check the console) and you're using d3.csv.parse the wrong way : you should have something like :

```
data = d3.csv.parse(d3.select("pre#ddata").text(),function(data){
    return {
        date : data.date,
        premise : data.premise,
        apc : data.apc
    }
});
```

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#parse

Comment: that is not brace problem .. but that is because data is undefined. First please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890836/loading-external-csv-file-in-jsfiddle to understand what am I trying to do

Comment: There is an error l50 : data.forEach - check it : data is not an array but an object representing the line (you can't loop that way)

Comment: thanks topheman .. any suggestions on how to get this working. m still stuck

Comment: I tried some things, but your use case is too large. 1) Chnage to `data = d3.csv.parse(...` and use Date objects (you also have that kind of problems when using d3 date helpers, your not passing Date objects but strings)